# Alternative triangle inequality proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, fake-proofs

I have looked everywhere for confirmation of this proof of the triangle inequality with no success.

Prove the triangle inequality:

$$\vert x + y \vert \leq \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert.$$

Proof:

Given the definition of $|x|$ to be $|x| = \max\{-x, x\}$. We know that $x \leq \vert x \vert$ and $y \leq \vert y \vert$.

So:

$$\vert x + y \vert \leq \vert \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert \vert = \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert.$$

Thus, we have proven the triangle inequality:

$$\vert x + y \vert \leq \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert.$$

What is wrong with it? If nothing is wrong with this proof, why is it not readily used as it seems to be quite concise.

Comment: How did you conclude that $\vert x + y \vert \leq \vert \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert \vert$ ?

Comment: Using the assumption $x \leq \vert x \vert$ similarly for y.

Comment: Well it seems that you have gone from $a \leq b$ and $c \leq d$ to $\vert a+c \vert \leq \vert b+d \vert$, which does not generally follow. Consider something like $-2 \leq 1$ and $-3 \leq 2$ for example.

Comment: From the assumptions that were made in the first line of the proof, I do not see how that is a valid counter example. Using your $a$ and $c$, we have $\vert -2 - 3 \vert \leq \vert \vert -2 \vert + \vert -3 \vert \vert = \vert 2 + 3 \vert$

Comment: It is not counter example to the triangle inequality, it is counter example to the "$a \leq b $ and $c \leq d$ implies $\vert a+c \vert \leq \vert b+d \vert$" which you seemed to have used to conclude $\vert x + y \vert \leq \vert \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert \vert$.

Comment: So because the assumption used does not generalize to other applications it is in bad form to use it? Would it help if the bounds on the assumption were more clear, like: $-\vert x \vert \leq x \leq \vert x \vert$? I appreciate your input!

Comment: Maybe try: $|x|= x$ if  $x \geq 0$, $|x|=-x$ otherwise. Then your step is easily justified with cases, although this is partly self-defeating since it more or less proves the triangle inequality in general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $x\le|x|$ and $y\le|y|$ you can deduce
$$
x+y\le |x|+|y|
$$
On the other hand, from $-x\le|x|$ and $-y\le|y|$ you can deduce
$$
-x-y\le|x|+|y|
$$
that's the same as
$$
x+y\ge-(|x|+|y|)
$$
The two inequalities say
$$
-(|x|+|y|)\le x+y\le |x|+|y|
$$
so
$$
|x+y|\le|x|+|y|
$$

You didn't use both conditions.

Answer (score 2):

$$(1)\; |x|+|y|=\max (x,-x) +|y|\geq  x+|y|= x+\max (y,-y)\geq x+y.$$ $$(2)\;|x|+|y|= \max (x,-x) +|y|\geq -x+|y|=-x+\max (y,-y)\geq -x-y.$$ $$ \text {Therefore }\; |x|+|y|\geq \max (x+y,-x-y)= |x+y|.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider two vectors $x$ and $y$, and describe a vector $z$ on Euclidean space given by:
\begin{equation}
|z\rangle = \frac{|x\rangle}{|x|} - \frac{|y\rangle}{|y|} \label{newvec} \tag{1} .
\end{equation}
Now, we know that on Euclidean spaces, the norm of any vector, including $z$ in (\ref{newvec}) will be positive definite
$$|z|^2 = \langle z | z \rangle \geq 0$$
$$\Rightarrow \qquad \frac{\langle x | x \rangle}{|x|^2} + \frac{\langle y | y \rangle}{|y|^2} - \frac{\langle x | y \rangle + \langle y | x \rangle}{|x| |y|} = 1 + 1 - \frac{\langle x | y \rangle + \langle y | x \rangle}{|x| |y|} \geq 0$$
\begin{equation}
\therefore \qquad 2 |x| |y| \geq \langle x | y \rangle + \langle y | x \rangle \label{cond} \tag{2} .
\end{equation}
If we consider the norm of the sum of vectors $x$ and $y$, then we shall have:
\begin{equation}
\left| x + y \right|^2 = |x|^2 + |y|^2 + \langle x | y \rangle + \langle y | x \rangle \label{normsum} \tag{3} ,
\end{equation}
while the sum of the norms gives us:
\begin{equation}
\left( |x| + |y| \right)^2 = |x|^2 + |y|^2 + 2 |x| |y| \label{sumnorm}\tag{4} .
\end{equation}
Thus, comparing (\ref{normsum}) to (\ref{sumnorm}) and applying (\ref{cond}), we can see that:
$$\left( |x| + |y| \right)^2 \geq \left| x + y \right|^2$$
\begin{equation}
\Rightarrow \qquad |x| + |y| \geq \left| x + y \right| \tag{5}.
\end{equation}
Thus, proving the Triangle Inequality.